# determining whether a graph on $8$ vertices is nonplanar

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Determine, with justification, whether the graph $G$ below is nonplanar.

[image]

I'm not sure whether the graph is planar. I can't really see how to find a planar embedding for it, despite having attempted to draw it with no edges crossing.

Comment: One way of (trying) to do this is to imagine the graph in three dimensions and then "untangle" it if possible. It is always possible to realise such a graph in three dimensions without any edges crossing (there is enough freedom in placing vertices).

Comment: That's probably why planar graphs are defined in $2$-d; in $3$-d every graph would be "planar."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graph is indeed planar, as shown here:

[image]